# How to downgrade PHP 5.4 to 5.1.6 using xammp.

Tags: php, xampp

Hi I would like to know if there is a way where I can downgrade my PHP version to 5.1.6 to using the current version of xammp? 
I need this PHP version in one of my clients existing intranet application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

In order to downgrade PHP in XAMPP it's probably easiest to downgrade XAMPP itself: see [Xampp Sourcefourge Files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/)

Comment: OK thanks for your reply, how will I know what version of xammp support 5.1.6?

Comment: I found out, that Xampp 1.5.4 is supporting the PHP 5.1.6. You only have to google for the version history, like: "xampp php 5.1.6"

Comment: In case somebody else needs xampp version history: http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/xampp-version-history-apache-mysql-php/